# adding click-to-call to php echo statement

Tags: php, html

Im sure there is a simple explanation to this but I cant find an answer to this anywhere. This is a function that is called on the header to display phone number.  Im trying to add the click-to-call tracking to this but when I add it, it breaks the site. So

This is the current code:

```
function themeblvd_header_contact() {
  $link_address = 'tel:3026560214';
  echo "<div class='contact-number'>Contact us at <a href='$link_address'>(302) 656-0214</a></div>";
}
```

When I add the click-to-call is when it breaks:

```
$link_address = 'tel:3026560214'; 
echo "<div class='contact-number'>Contact us at <a onclick="ga('send', 'event',
'phone number', 'click to call', '3026560214', 1);" href='$link_address'>(302) 656-0214</a></div>";
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks the site"? What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: You need to escape double quotes. `echo "<div class='contact-number'>Contact us at <a onclick="` <-- see it

Comment: The site just goes blank. no error codes.

Comment: See above ^ that's your problem. Add error reporting in the future, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: What IDE are you using? Didn't it tell you you had an error? Otherwise the error on your website should give you a clue to what is wrong.

Comment: Just take a look at the syntax highlighting. You need to know how to debug simple syntax errors like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are closing the string in the middle of it and then making a new one, two quotes to much is probably the problem here. try to escape the string like this.

```
$link_address = 'tel:3026560214'; 
echo "<div class='contact-number'>Contact us at <a onclick=\"ga('send', 'event',
'phone number', 'click to call', '3026560214', 1);\" href='$link_address'>(302) 656-0214</a></div>";
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that did it. So just for clarification if you don't mind, why is the forward slash before quotation at the end of the onclick?

Comment: @AngelHerrera Because the `"` would end your string without being escaped with a `\`.

Comment: You start your string with a double qoute, right. the `\"`basically says that the quoute is a part of the string. otherwise it would close the string that you pass to the echo. if that make more sense?